# VB Open file then disallow access

Tags: vb.net, file-access

My program will have to be run on different computers at the same time in the future. How can I open the file when my app loads up, then deny access to anything else EXCEPT the current instance of my app? (first come first serve for access to the file).

Or a way to just flag the file in a particular way and I can run a check on Form Load to see if it is flagged or not and pseudo-lock it by just disabling any button that triggers interactions with the file.

This is just to prevent more than one person from working with the same file at once.

Basically any method to allow this will be fine. I just need a starting point and I can tweak and optimize as I go on.

Comment: Do you need to lock this file from other computers accessing it?  Is this a network resource?  Do you just need to be exclusive on it on a single machine?  Also see my questions from my comment below.  Please update the question with more information to help provide you with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file with the [File.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in [FileShare.None](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) as your sharing type.  This will restrict others from opening the file.

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
```

**Edit:**
Just guessing from some of your other questions that you are calling `XElement.Load` on this file later in your application.  One of the overload for Load takes a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838544(v=vs.110).aspx).  The `File.Open` method returns you a `FileStream`.  You could just open the file immediately on application open, and then when you are ready to read the XML file, just pass the `FileStream` into `XElement.Load`.

Comment: I did try this at one point but I also have to  use use `.Load` for an XML file. And it fails to load because I used File.Open. I need a way to be able to flag the file as open so OTHERS can't access it and be able to work with it within the program until the Form Closed event. If this is even possible. Or something like it?

Comment: I would assume from your comment that you use .Load on this same file not some other XML file, correct?  So you need to Load the same file later in the process?  Are you writing to it during this process.  Can you clarify your question with details of how you are using this file later in the application?  Can you show an example of your load call?